# Do damage rig effects stack with non-rig damage modules without penalty?

Tags: eve-online

The description for **`Hybrid Rig Collision Accelerator I`**, a rig slot damage increaser, warns that:

> Penalty: Using more than one type of this module or similar modules
>   that affect the same attribute on the ship will be penalized.

A **`Magnetic Field Stabilizer I`**, a low-slot damage increaser, carries the same warning.

Does that mean that a ship equiped with both would suffer the stacking penality?

Or does the penalty only focus on the same slot type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this out with the above items and **there did not appear to be any stacking penalty** between the rig slot and the low slot items.

Thus stacking penalties may be restricted by slot.

Answer (score 0):

They count against each other for stacking penalties.